# Google sheets resetting reference after deleting and replacing a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets one and two. one references two. I need to delete the entire sheet two and replace it with another one that is similar. After I do that, one can not from the reference anymore even though sheet two is now there.

The only fix that I have found so far is to go to that cell and press `enter` on it again. Refreshing it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to get google sheets to automatically find the reference without having to go through and press `enter` on everything?

Comment: maybe through scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just not possible in a scale you imagine it. best you can do is to use **`=INDIRECT()`** when you reference between sheets. this way you can have a cell in sheet-one with the name of the sheet-two and when you want to replace sheet-two with sheet-two-new then you just re-write that sheet name in that cell and do it in this way:

- prepare whole sheet-two-new to be ready to replace sheet two
- rewrite cell for the reference
- delete sheet-two
- rename sheet-two-new to sheet-two